# Multiple QueryDef/CopyFromRecordset duplicating data

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

So, I'm having some issues with a DAO pull in Excel 2013.  I've pasted my code below for review.

The issue I'm having is, the 2nd `CopyFromRecordset` duplicates the data from the first.  Eg:

- First pull is 1500 lines
- Second pull should be 1200 lines from **different tables**

  - Second pull instead is the same 1500 lines as the first pull

I've attempted to isolate the problem, and added some watches to the DB/Qry/RS variables, and they all checkout, as well as the SQL lines.  I added some 'close' and 'Nothing' lines for each of the variables to attempt to clear any residual data I was missing.  I even tried clearing the clipboard with a `CutCopyMode=False` statement; that didn't work either.

Everything else about the code below works, except the data it's spitting out.  I have two other pulls I need to perform from the same database, but would like to figure these out before I mess with those, ha ha.

Thank you in advance for your help!!

```
Dim dt_EndDate As Date

Dim wkbk_PMC As Workbook


Dim MyDatabase As DAO.Database
Dim MyQueryDef As DAO.QueryDef
Dim MyRecordset As DAO.Recordset
Dim MyTableDef As DAO.TableDef

dt_EndDate = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date) + 2, 0)

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.StatusBar = "Generating Reports..."
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set wkbk_PMC = Workbooks.Add

    With wkbk_PMC
        .SaveAs Filename:=CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").specialfolders("Desktop") & "\" & Month(Date) & "-" & Day(Date) & "-" & Year(Date) & " - Coordinator Weekly Meeting"
    End With

Set MyDatabase = DBEngine.OpenDatabase("N:\Database\Coordinator Reports.accdb")
Set MyQueryDef = MyDatabase.QueryDefs("qry_DRReport_CNP")

With MyQueryDef
    .Parameters("[dt_EndDate]") = dt_EndDate
End With

Set MyRecordset = MyQueryDef.OpenRecordset

wkbk_PMC.Sheets(1).Range("A3").CopyFromRecordset MyRecordset
For i = 1 To MyRecordset.Fields.Count
    wkbk_PMC.Sheets(1).Cells(2, i).Value = MyRecordset.Fields(i - 1).Name
Next i

MyRecordset.Close           ' Added to attempt to sever all connection to previous DB/Qry/RS
MyQueryDef.Close            ' Added to attempt to sever all connection to previous DB/Qry/RS
MyDatabase.Close            ' Added to attempt to sever all connection to previous DB/Qry/RS
Set MyRecordset = Nothing   ' Added to attempt to sever all connection to previous DB/Qry/RS
Set MyQueryDef = Nothing    ' Added to attempt to sever all connection to previous DB/Qry/RS
Set MyDatabase = Nothing    ' Added to attempt to sever all connection to previous DB/Qry/RS

Set MyDatabase = DBEngine.OpenDatabase("N:\Database\Coordinator Reports.accdb")
Set MyQueryDef = MyDatabase.QueryDefs("qry_DRReport_CCP")

With MyQueryDef
    .Parameters("[dt_EndDate]") = dt_EndDate
End With

Set MyRecordset = MyQueryDef.OpenRecordset

lRow = wkbk_PMC.Sheets(1).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

wkbk_PMC.Sheets(1).Range("A" & (lRow + 1)).CopyFromRecordset MyRecordset

MyRecordset.Close
MyQueryDef.Close
MyDatabase.Close
```

Comment: Have you checked that the two stored queries are actually pulling the expected data when fed with the same date parameter ?  `qry_DRReport_CCP` and `qry_DRReport_CNP` ?

Comment: Yes.  I've opened the ACCESS database, and run the queries from there manually entering the date range, and they each pull the correct data from their respective tables.